# Sending Push Notification To All iOS Users Of App Using PHP

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using this PHP to send out push notifications to just one user of my app.  Everything works great with that, but I need to send it to all users:

```
$deviceToken = 'DeviceTokenHere';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'Passphrase Here';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'There are 2 new requests at the bottom of the list.  Please check them out.';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

How would I alter this to send it to all users?

Comment: Simple. Query your users database and create for loop for each user in your result running the above code

Comment: I don't have a database set up for each user @PanayotPanayotov

Comment: First thing you need to do is to create a database to store all your user's UDID. Then every time you need to send a notification just take all device UDID's from your users database and run the code above to push your notification to all users. Without database you need to manualy insert every UDID and send notification, or use pre-defined set of UDID's

Comment: Thanks.  Would you be able to direct me to a good tutorial on creating a database?  My main area I work in is iOS, so even this PHP was a bit outside of my comfort zone.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($deviceToken in $allDevices) {
    SendPushToDevice($deviceToken);
}
```

Note! If count of $allDevices > 100, then you must do it with some time intervals, otherwise push will not delivered.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allDevices); $i++) {
    if ($i > 0 && $i % 100 == 0) {
        // your sleep function
    } else {
        $deviceToken = $allDevices[$i];
        SendPushToDevice($deviceToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding where this fits in with the rest of my PHP Script.  I have no database of deviceTokens at all.

Comment: Then you must have it :)